How convert list of oracle table description into json?
I have a question about how to build a query from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS and get table_name, column_name and data_types as a JSON structure?
For example I have this select:
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT('nombre' IS TABLE_NAME, 'campo' IS COLUMN_NAME, 'tipo' IS DATA_TYPE)
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
    OWNER = 'PERSONAL'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTOMER__C';

and the result is something like:
{"nombre":"CUSTOMER__C","campo":"ID","tipo":"NVARCHAR2"}
{"nombre":"CUSTOMER__C","campo":"OWNERID","tipo":"NVARCHAR2"}

I need to know the best way to take this result:
CUSTOMER__C  ID NVARCHAR2
CUSTOMER__C  OWNERID    NVARCHAR2
CUSTOMER__C  ISDELETED  NUMBER
CUSTOMER__C  NAME   NVARCHAR2

And convert into something like this:
{
    "nombre": "CUSTOMER__C",
    "fields": [
        {
            "campo": "ID",
            "tipo": "varchar"
        },
        {
            "campo": "OWNERID",
            "tipo": "timestamp"
         },
         {
            "campo": "OWNERID",
            "tipo": "timestamp"
         },
         {
         },
            
    ]
}

There is someone that help me to build this query?

In order to aggregate all of the columns of the table you need to wrap them in a JSON_ARRAYAGG() function.  Then remember to group by the table name.  I've used the Oracle table EDITION$ to demonstrate.  I wrapped the output with a JSON_SERIALIZE() function to pretty it up.
SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE(
          JSON_OBJECT( 'nombre' VALUE table_name
                      , 'fields' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT( 'campo' VALUE column_name
                                                                , 'tipo' VALUE data_type))
                      ) PRETTY) EXAMPLE_JSON 
 FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'EDITION$'
 GROUP BY table_name;   

Which outputs:
{
  "nombre" : "EDITION$",
  "fields" :
  [
    {
      "campo" : "OBJ#",
      "tipo" : "NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "SPARE2",
      "tipo" : "VARCHAR2"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "SPARE1",
      "tipo" : "NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "AUDIT$",
      "tipo" : "VARCHAR2"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "CODE",
      "tipo" : "BLOB"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "FLAGS",
      "tipo" : "NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "campo" : "P_OBJ#",
      "tipo" : "NUMBER"
    }
  ]
}

